# How to import data in matlab from a csv that contains strings numbers and blank cells

Tags: matlab, import

I have a csv that contains a single column with a lot of data in it. The data is a variety of strings, numbers and blanks, where I want to keep it in the exact order including all of the blank cells. So an example of the data would be:

A

05

G

12

I have tried to use importdata and this works perfectly, the problem is my csv has over 1 million rows and for some reason using importdata only imports to just over the first 100k rows.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `csvread`, it only works for numerical values.
If the file is too big, try the `fopen` and then `fgets` (see the docs).